# Navigate between fragments using one button in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager2

I'm developing an application in android studio (using Java), that needs to switch between 3 screens until it arrives to a game.
for example:

```
Screen A (user input and a question + button to continue) -> when pressing the button the input pass to the screen B
Screen B (user input and a question + button to continue) -> when pressing the button the input pass to the screen C
Screen C (user input and a question + button to continue) -> when pressing the button the input saved in DB and we start a new game.
```

It's like the process of registration, but with multiple screens.
My question here is how can I implement this using fragments? I think that since the screens are
alike (and the only thing that changed is the question) fragments will be the best option.
but when I tried to implement that, I didn't succeed to make the button switch between 3 screens, only 2.
I also read about ViewPager2, but multiple errors occurred when I tried to use it.
In addition, each fragment needs to keep the input of the previous fragment + play different record.
Is there any good implementation to achieve this scenarios?

Comment: Are you using a tablayout?

Comment: actually, I didn't knew what is this layout till you mentioned it

Comment: removed `android-studio` tag, as that tag is for questions/problems in Android Studio. Your problem is unrelated to Android Studio itself.